# Combine python list of dictionary and add one of the key:value pair

Tags: python

### Problem

- I want to combine a dictionary from the same list that has the same key:value (championId)
- Compare a different key:value and replace the smallest value (championLevel)
- Add/Sum a different key:value (championPoints)
- The rest of the key:value does not matter right now, I just want the 3 data above to be combined

### What I tried

```
from collections import Counter

someList = [{'id': 1, 'lvl' : 7, 'pts' : 10},
            {'id': 5, 'lvl' : 2, 'pts' : 3},
            {'id': 1, 'lvl' : 2, 'pts' : 10}]
summed = Counter()
for d in someList:
    summed[d['id]] += d['pts']
summed
resultList = [{'id':id, 'pts':pts} for id, pts in summed.most_common()]
```

`[{'id': 1, 'pts': 20}, {'id': 5, 'pts': 3}]`

### Example data I am using

```
[
    {
        "championId": 92,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 458884,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647063907000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 437284,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": false,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    },
    {
        "championId": 51,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 225748,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647180539000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 204148,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": true,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    },
    {
        "championId": 92,
        "championLevel": 5,
        "championPoints": 39721,
        "lastPlayTime": 1648801756000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 18121,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": true,
        "tokensEarned": 2
    }
]
```

### What I want as a result

```
[
    {
        "championId": 92,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 498605,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647063907000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 437284,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": false,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    },
    {
        "championId": 51,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 225748,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647180539000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 204148,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": true,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be fairly straight forward in pandas.  Just load the list of dicts into a dataframe, and build an aggregation dict to decide what to do w/each column.

In this case we have one max, one sum, and the rest default to 'first'.  As you decide what to do w/each column you can add them to `agg`

```
import pandas as pd

l = [
    {
        "championId": 92,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 458884,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647063907000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 437284,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": False,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    },
    {
        "championId": 51,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 225748,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647180539000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 204148,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": True,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    },
    {
        "championId": 92,
        "championLevel": 5,
        "championPoints": 39721,
        "lastPlayTime": 1648801756000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 18121,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": True,
        "tokensEarned": 2
    }
]

agg = {'championLevel':'min','championPoints':'sum'}

for col in df:
    if col not in agg.keys():
        agg[col] = 'first'
        
pd.DataFrame(l).groupby('championId').agg(agg).to_dict('records')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that `true` and `false` are lowercase in your input I assume you have JSON data, not a Python list, so you need to first parse the JSON using `json.loads()` and then you can loop over all the entries in the array. If you don't have JSON you will need to replace `true`/ `false` with `True` or `False` and you can skip the step with parsing the JSON.

For each entry store the champion in the dictionary using `championId` as key if we have not seen this champion before. Or if we have seen the same champion before set the level to the maximum of the stored and the current value and last but not least sum up the points of the already stored and the current champ.

To get a list again use `list(champ_dict.values())` and to get the expected result use `json.dumps()` to output the result.

```py
import json

input_json = """
[
    {
        "championId": 92,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 458884,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647063907000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 437284,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": false,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    },
    {
        "championId": 51,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 225748,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647180539000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 204148,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": true,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    },
    {
        "championId": 92,
        "championLevel": 5,
        "championPoints": 39721,
        "lastPlayTime": 1648801756000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 18121,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": true,
        "tokensEarned": 2
    }
]
"""

input = json.loads(input_json)

champ_dict = dict()
for cur_champ in input:
    champ_id = cur_champ["championId"]
    if champ_id in champ_dict:
        champion = champ_dict[champ_id]
        champion["championLevel"] = max(champion["championLevel"], cur_champ["championLevel"])
        champion["championPoints"] += cur_champ["championPoints"]
    else:
        champ_dict[champ_id] = cur_champ

champ_output = list(champ_dict.values())
print(json.dumps(champ_output, indent=4))
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        "championId": 92,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 498605,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647063907000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 437284,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": false,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    },
    {
        "championId": 51,
        "championLevel": 7,
        "championPoints": 225748,
        "lastPlayTime": 1647180539000,
        "championPointsSinceLastLevel": 204148,
        "championPointsUntilNextLevel": 0,
        "chestGranted": true,
        "tokensEarned": 0
    }
]
```